# WPF C# - Can't dervie from System.Windows.Media.Geometry CS1729

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I am trying to create my own `PolarPathGeometry` class. I have successfully created a shape that is similar to what I want, but I want to draw it faster using `GeometryDrawing` and `DrawingImage` as a source for an image.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace System.Windows.Media
{

    [ContentProperty("Figures")]
    public sealed partial class PolarPathGeometry : Geometry //CS1729 here
    {
       public override bool IsEmpty()
       {

           throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool MayHaveCurves()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
 }
```

Is there an Workaround or other suggestions how to realize it?

Comment: can't post images, so far the testclass:
//CS1729 is showning here
 public sealed partial class PolarPathGeometry : Geometry
    {
        public override bool IsEmpty()
        {
            
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool MayHaveCurves()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

Comment: You're not supposed to use pictures of code. And don't add code to the comments. [edit] your post and add relevant code and error messages AS TEXT, [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). See also: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Edit is done, so hope u can answer

Comment: The class's own [Notes to implements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometry?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#notes-to-implementers) say you can't inherit from it. `Although this class is abstract, it is not publicly extensible.` This isn't a generic GIS class, it's specific to Windows.Media and WPF 2D drawing.

Comment: Are you looking for spatial classes? In that case check [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite). Several projections are provided in the companion [ProjNet4GeoAPI](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI) . The library is the de-facto standard for storing spatial data in ADO.NET/EF Core

Comment: Hey Panagiotes,...The transform was not the problem, to draw it faster is what i looking for